# The set of irrationals in the reals is open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

> The set of irrationals in the reals is open or closed?

I only know that the set of irrational numbers neither closed nor open so this set is **neither closed nor open**. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, you're correct.

Comment: @florence..can you give hint to how to prove this

Comment: Hint: is $\mathbb{Q}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$? (use the basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$). Then, is $\mathbb{Q}$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$? Find a limit point not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @suresh Try a proof by contradiction. If $\mathbb{Q}^C$ were open, then what? Similarly for closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that the set of irrational numbers is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that between any two distinct real numbers there exists an irrational number (that is, every open interval contains an irrational number). The same is true for the rationals.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Let $B=(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ be an open ball around $x$. Then there exists a rational number in $B$, since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$. Since every open ball centered at a point in $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ contains a point not in $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is not open. The same reasoning shows that $\mathbb Q$ is not open, and so $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is not closed.

Comment: @florence..thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You are Correct!

Here's my reason: Pick $0 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus I$. For any $\epsilon>0$, $(0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon)$ contains irrational points such as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ for large $n$. So $\mathbb{R} \setminus I$ is not open and hence $I$ is not closed.